# How can I determine if dishwasher control panel needs replacing?

Tags: dishwasher

Three year old dishwasher just stops filling with water one day. The diswahser continues through the remainder of the cycle without ever filling with water. If the water supply is available, are there any mechanical issues to investigate? If this is indicative of a faulty control panel, how can I test that?

I'd like to confirm it is the control panel before I replace it.

Comment: What makes you suspect the control panel?  What is the make and model of the unit?

Comment: It's a Kitchen Aid Model #W10311121B. I suspect its control panel because several product reviews and consumer complaints note that after three years they reported replacing the control panel. What else should I suspect?

Comment: How can one check the valve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some dishwashers have a float switch gadget in the base water tray that floats up with the water level. Should the water level rise too high this activates a switch that cuts off the water supply valve to prevent the dishwasher from flooding the kitchen. I have seen situations where the float unit gets stuck in its upper position and prevents any water filling to occur. In one case the float mechanism got jammed up due to food debris trapped under it.

Check to see if your unit has a thing like this and clean it out and check for free travel of the float mechanism.